# Do we have any media of Lando and Han interacting between Solo and ESB?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the end of [*Solo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story) (2018), after having a messy, contentious relationship with Han, Lando abandons him in the Millennium Falcon. Han returns to win the ship and then departs.

About 13 years later, in *The Empire Strikes Back* (1980) Han turns to Lando for help, believing that he'll get it and trusting Lando to a degree.

Obviously, this implies they had some sort of relationship (or at least interacted) in that stretch of time.

Are there any books or other sources that mention them working together or anything in this time frame?

Comment: Non-Legends, I assume?

Answer (score 3):

In [*You Owe Me a Ride*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/You_Owe_Me_a_Ride), one of the (ambiguously-)canon short stories in [*From a Certain Point of View*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View), the Tonnika sisters allude to a previous occasion where they'd worked with Han that they refer to as "[the Lando ordeal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lando_ordeal)":

> Brea and Senni discussed the job over and over again through the night and into the next morning.
>
> "I say [Han] won't come with us," Brea said.
>
> "He can't still be mad about the Lando ordeal. It was *his* idea."
>
> <sub>From a Certain Point of View, Kindle edition, page 161</sub>

This must be referring to an event that took place after *Solo*, since the Tonnika sisters were involved, and since Han apparently knew Lando at the time.